# How to format a message so that it is displayed in "XAML Binding Failures"-Toolwindow in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

How to format a message so that it is displayed in "XAML Binding Failures"-Toolwindow in Visual Studio?

If i try:

```
TraceSource bindingTrace = PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource;
bindingTrace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 0, "message ");
```

a message is displayed.

[image]

I would like to specify the other columns for e.g. Target or TargetType.
Any Ideas?

Comment: You can refer to [XAML Binding Failure Troubleshooting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improvements-to-xaml-tooling-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-7-preview-1/#xaml-binding-failure-troubleshooting) to get  the use of `XAML Binding Failure` tool. With the testing of `Validation.HasError`, you can see other column.

Comment: I have developed my own binding and would like to create my own message in that toolwindow.

Comment: Do you mean create your `Binding Path` , `Target` and `Target Type` like `message` for Description? I think these value of terms should be determined by practical application, why do you want to re-assign?

Comment: Imagine you are developing your own (extended) binding and something goes wrong and you want to publish an error message about it. Sure, I can write that to the debug console, that's how WPF used to do it. But now there is this new toolwindow and binding errors appear there. Now I would like to display my own errors there as well.

Comment: This cannot be done with special formatting of the message. The framework calls [BindingDiagnostics.NotifyBindingFailed](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Diagnostics/BindingDiagnostics.cs,9bdb1f62d2838fb6,references), which is internal and dependent on a `BindingExpressionBase`.
Visual Studio is watching for those events and probably gets the additional information directly from the `BindingExpressionBase`. Unfortunately Microsoft really likes their internal hidden functionality, when it comes to WPF.